# AuthorizeNet Omnipay Error

Tags: laravel, ssl, authorize.net, omnipay

I am using omnipay package for my payment method in authorized.
I have two site on the same server, one is a live site that runs ssl  and one that is for testing purposes only and do not run ssl.

Now, i dont have problem on paying in our testing site which it runs within our expectation. But, it seems odd in our live site because after entering my billing information, it returns an error that says:

```
  An error occurred while trying to report this transaction to the merchant. An e-mail has been sent to the merchant informing them of the error. The following is the result of the attempt to charge your credit card. 

  This transaction has been approved.

  It is advisable for you to contact the merchant to verify that you will receive the product or service.
```

Where do u think the problem lies? I really need help on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This means the relay response URL used by your application is not returning a successful response to Authorize.Net in time (5 seconds). As a result Authorize.Net is assuming the page is not functioning and displaying that message.

You either need to verify  the URL is correct, not error-ing out, and responding within a few seconds.